# No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager' : while trying to extend IdentityUser?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I am using asp.net core on a mac machine, I am trying to create a custom ApplicationUser for my asp.net mvc web application which works very fine with the base IdentityUser.

Despite following this guide by Microsoft:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/add-user-data?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio

I am faced by this error:

> {"error":"No service for type
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]'
>   has been registered."}

Here are snippets of my code:

**startup.cs**

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {

        // [...]

        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(
            options => options.UseSqlServer(identityDbContextConnection));
        // Relevant part: influences the error
        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();


        services.AddMvc(config =>
        {
            var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                             .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                             .Build();
            config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
        });
    }
```

**ApplicationUser.cs**

```
    // Add profile data for application users by adding properties to the ApplicationUser class
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    [Required]
    public string DrivingLicense { get; set; }
}
```

**Register.cshtml.cs**

```
public class RegisterModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    private readonly ILogger<RegisterModel> _logger;
    private readonly IServiceProvider _services;

    public RegisterModel(
        UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
        SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager,
        ILogger<RegisterModel> logger,
        IServiceProvider services
    )
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        _logger = logger;
        _services = services;
    }

    [BindProperty]
    public InputModel Input { get; set; }

    public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }

    public class InputModel
    {
        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        // Added for ApplicationUser
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Driving License")]
        public string DrivingLicense { get; set; }
        // -----------------------------
        // [...]
    }

    public void OnGet(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser { 
                UserName = Input.Email, 
                Email = Input.Email, 
                DrivingLicense = Input.DrivingLicense // property added by ApplicationUser
            };
            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {

                _logger.LogInformation("User created a new account with password.");

                await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
            }
            foreach (var error in result.Errors)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return Page();
    }
}
```

Snippets from **Manage/Index.cshtml.cs**

```
public class InputModel
    {
        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        // Added for ApplicationUser
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Driving License")]
        public string DrivingLicense { get; set; }
        // -----------------------------

        [Phone]
        [Display(Name = "Phone number")]
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    }



public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Page();
        }

        // [...]

        // Added for ApplicationUser
        if (Input.DrivingLicense != user.DrivingLicense)
        {
            user.DrivingLicense = Input.DrivingLicense;
        }
        await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);
        // -------------------------

        await _signInManager.RefreshSignInAsync(user);
        StatusMessage = "Your profile has been updated";
        return RedirectToPage();
    }
```

**ApplicationDbContext**

```
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}
```

The only part I couldn't follow from the official microsoft guide is the one editing Account/Manage/Index.cshtml because the file was not scaffolded when I did the CLI step !

It is noted that when I replace ApplicationUser by IdentityUser in **startup.cs** as follow:
`services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()` the application opens but ofcourse registration does not work properly as expected.

Comment: Perhaps an other place where you're injecting the non-generic `UserManager`?

Comment: Also see https://adrientorris.github.io/aspnet-core/identity/extend-user-model.html

Comment: I've already stumbled up on that one before , it doesn't have any effect . And anyway it was on 2016 ; a lot of things change in asp.net core

Comment: Try to search `IdentityUser` through `Entire Solution`, will you find any `IdentityUser`?  What is the step for `the file was not scaffolded`? Do you get any error while scaffolding? Try to share us your demo project.

Comment: I have same problem too in ASP.NET Core 2.1. My other project that uses 2.0 works just fine. Somehow there is something that breaks the Startup.cs in 2.1. Let me know if you find the solution

Comment: .net core 2.1 is very different from 2.0. You must scaffold in your Identity system and work from there: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: Very thankful for this help ... Anyway I realized I have to give up on asp core once and for all after realizing that these are just quirks which we are stumbling up on. That's gonna waste a lot of developing time. I hope it's allowed to keep the question so that once a solution is found it helps other developers. Unless hopefully asp core newer iterations gets rid of these quirks hence this topic will be no longer relevant and I remove it.

Comment: Brother mahmoud have you solved  @mahmoudfathy ?

Answer (score 15):

The problem is in the '_LoginPartial.cshtml'

remove this

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@inject SignInManager<IdentityUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<IdentityUser> UserManager
```

Add this

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@inject SignInManager<ApplicationUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager
```

Comment: I can't believe this was my solution, after many hours of searching, thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

Had same issue with core 2.

One more area where you need to check is the file _ManageNav.cshtml in and there you have to update the line `@inject SignInManager<IdentityUser> SignInManager` with `@inject SignInManager<YOURCUSTOMMODEL> SignInManager`.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank u this was the one that ended up being at my fault u saved me hours

Answer (score 3):

In dotnet core 2.1 I faced the same issue,  below steps solved my problems

1 ) Extend the  IdentityUser or  IdentityRole

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<Guid>
{
    public DateTime JoinTime { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    public DateTime DOB { get; set; } = Convert.ToDateTime("01-Jan-1900");
}
public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole<Guid>
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

2 ) Update ApplicationDbContext class

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, Guid>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {

    }
}
```

3 ) Update Stratup.cs ConfigureServices

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

    services.AddScoped<IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser>, AppClaimsPrincipalFactory>();


    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

    services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultUI()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

}
```

Update _LoginPartial.cshtml (shared --> view )

```
@inject SignInManager<ApplicationUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager
```

Comment: The link to the msdocs said the requirements was .net core 2.2 or later your solution won't work. @Olawale answer got it

Answer (score 0):

in Asp.Net 7 and maybe 8

open **_Layout.cshtml**

and change

```
@inject SignInManager<IdentityUser> SignInManager
```

to

```
@inject SignInManager<User> SignInManager
```

Note : **User is name of custome model user Replace it with your model name**

and open **_ViewImports.cshtml**

and import model like this

```
@using Shop.Models.Accounts
```